# Where to instantiate objects stored in database?

Tags: python, mongodb, design-patterns, pymongo

Figuring out how to link object oriented code and database storage.

The Python MongoDB driver, `PyMongo`, returns results as dictionaries. I need to turn these into objects for further processing.

Assuming Data Access Objects (`DAO`) for each collection, hiding the MongoDB queries from the rest of the code.

#### Where should I create objects from their description in the database?

1. Create objects in main code

   The `DAO` method `get_buildings_by_date()` returns a building list as dictionaries.

   The `total_area_by_date()` method in the main code  calls `get_buildings_by_date()` to get a list of building descriptions as dictionaries, instantiates Building, then does the computations using the methods in Building.
2. Create objects in `DAO`

   The `DAO` method `get_buildings_by_age()` instantiates Building and returns a list of Building instances.

   The `total_area_by_date()` method calls `get_buildings_by_date()`, then does the computations using the methods in Building.
3. Call `DAO` from objects themselves

   The calls to `DAO` are in the Building class itself, hidden from the `total_area_by_date()` method.

   Building class has static methods to return Building instances. For instance, it has a `get_buildings_by_date()` class method that calls the `get_buildings_by_date()` method from the DB manager layer, creates required number of Building instances and returns them as a list.

   `total_area_by_date()` calls `Building.get_buildings_by_date()`, then works with Building instances.

Edit: Do not expose inter-collection links outside of database management. Objects should not contain references (`_id`) to related documents in the database. For instance, if each document of the Buildings collection has an owner element holding the `_id` of a document in the Persons collection, good layer separation would imply that either the owner is stripped away, either it is queried and returned as a Person instance as well.

I think I'm missing a design pattern, here. Any idea which solution (or any other) I should pick?

I've read a bit about `ODM`s (MongoEngine, MongoKit, MongoLite, Ming). Whether we will be using `pymongo` or an `ODM` is not decided, but tips about how `ODM`s in general or an `ODM` in particular answers/hides this issue are welcome.

#### Update

With repository pattern in mind, it makes sense to avoid solution 1, as the main code should not be exposed other stuff than the classes it acts upon.

I think 3. is what is done in MongoEngine.

Comment: Use the repository pattern to encapsulate persistence details away from the rest of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think this rules out solution 1. I have the feeling I am trying to reinvent what `ODM`s do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

> A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection.

- First, make sure you have a database-independent model. Whether or not you should build a fully-fledged domain model or just use a simple property bag model is another question, but irrelevant here.
- Build a repository that accepts your model objects for create and update operations, and returns model objects from read operations. **The DAOs are now an internal concept of the repository and not visible to the rest of the application.**
- Now the repository is responsible for mapping DAOs to model objects and vice-versa. If you can implement the mapping in a generic way, extract it from the repository into a dedicated mapper and use the mapper from the repository to adhere to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I think the repository pattern excludes solution 1. in my question. Not sure if it rules out solution 2. Anyway, some of my code would benefit from direct access to bson/json through `pymongo` using bson.dumps/loads and another part would rather use business logic classes and could use an `ODM` such as `MongoEngine`. I'm not sure how I can mix both in a clean fashion, but this is another question. Accepting your answer, as the more I read about the whole thing, the more I realize my question can't be easily answered.